# How to send toDataURL 'image/png' Object using http post?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've obtained an image from my local camera, using `HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL('image/png')`. I now want to send the image to my backend (Express/Node.js) server. I tried appending the image to a `FormData()` object, and sending via `http post` but that's not working. (I've verified that the `http post` call works when I append a `File` Object to `FormData` and then send. I've also verified that the image capture is working correctly). Any pointers as to how I should proceed to send the image via `http post`? (Note: I saw that there is an 
`HTMLCanvas​Element​.moz​GetAsFile()` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/mozGetAsFile, but the MDN documentation says that this method is not recommended for production use).

Front-end image capture (Angular `capture-image.component.ts`)

```
  takePicture() {
    let context: CanvasRenderingContext2D  = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

    if (this.width && this.height) {
      this.canvasRef.nativeElement.width = this.width;
      this.canvasRef.nativeElement.height = this.height;
      context.drawImage(this.videoRef.nativeElement, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);

      let data = this.canvasRef.nativeElement.toDataURL('image/png');
      this.photoRef.nativeElement.src = data;

      let fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('image', data);
      try {
          this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/selection/test-photo",fd)
          .subscribe(
            (res) => {
              console.log("Successful result: " + JSON.stringify(res))},
            (err) => {
              console.log("Subscribe error: " + JSON.stringify(err))} 
        );
      }
      catch(e) {
        console.log("Caught error: " + e);
      }
    } else {
      this.clearPhoto();
    }
  }
```

Backend function (Express)

```
exports.selection_test_photo = [
    (req,res,next) => {
        const photo = new Photo();
        photo.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
        photo.photo.contentType = 'image/png';
        photo.save(function(err){
            if (err) {return next(err)};
            res.json({"foo": "bar"});
        });        
    },

];
```

Comment: Can you also share your backend function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method along with the [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method that accepts a filename,

```
      this.canvasRef.nativeElement.toBlob(blob => {
        this.photoRef.nativeElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('image', blob, "filename");
        this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/selection/test-photo",fd)
          .subscribe(
            (res) => {
              console.log("Successful result: " + JSON.stringify(res))},
            (err) => {
              console.log("Subscribe error: " + JSON.stringify(err))} 
        );
      },'image/png');
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Avin Kavish. I'm getting error `"Argument 1 of HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob is not an object."`

Comment: Oh sorry, check my edits, you have to pass a callback.

Comment: I'm using `multer` on the back-end. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yeah. no worries. I've never used multer so I didn't recognise the syntax.